# Non-negative matrix factorization for sparse input

Tags: matrix, matrix-factorization

Looking for some software to deal with 50kx50k sparse matrix applying non-negative matrix factorization. Do you know any?

Comment: Third hit in google leads me here:  http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/phoyer/software.html

Comment: It would help if you were a bit more verbose on what exactly you mean with "non-negative", and what kinds of factorizations you are looking for. What do you happen to know about your matrix?

Comment: [non-negative matrix factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) is a thing

Comment: @k20, several terms are "a thing", but it would not hurt to be descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

The following paper uses MapReduce for distributed computation of non-negative matrix factorization:

- J. Yin, L. Gao, Zh. Zhang, "[Scalable Nonnegative Matrix Factorization
  with Block-wise Updates](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-44845-8_22)," in *Proc. Eu. Conf. Machine Learning Knowledge Discovery*, Nancy, France, Sep. 2014, pp.337-352.

This paper describes an implementation and parallelization of the non-negative factorization and claims the results for matrices exceeding your specifications.

Regarding software libraries:

- python library [NIMFA](http://mloss.org/software/view/397/) supports both dense and sparse input ([associated paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/zitnik12a/zitnik12a.pdf))
- [R-package NMF](https://github.com/renozao/NMF) (no info on sparse that I was able to find quickly)
- [NMF Matrix toolbox](https://sites.google.com/site/nmftool/) (v 1.4 added support for sparse input)
- high-performance library [SmallK](https://smallk.github.io/), supports both dense and sparse

Comment: https://github.com/maximilianbehr/cuNMF for a GPU accelerated implementation. 50k-x-50k should be possible on a more recent GPU.